# Difficulty in understanding Permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have given a question of Permutation and Combinations along with its solution. I couldn't understand even a bit of it. I am an extreme  beginner . A detailed explanation is highly appreciated

```
POV :- But I know Beggar's method but couldn't understand the solution :(
```

Question :-

Let 20 identical objects are to be distributed among A and B. Find number of ways if $ 5 \le N_a \le 8 $ and $ 7 \le N_b \le 10 $ . All objects should be distributed.
( Where $ N_a $ is number of objects distributed to A and $ N_b $ is number of objects distributed to B )

Solution :-

$ N_a \ge 5 $ and  $N_b \ge 7$

By beggar's rule

( Satisfying Lower bounds )

$ ^{8 + 6 - 1} \mathrm{ C }_{6 - 1} $   =       $ ^{13} \mathrm{ C }_{5}  $

Final Answer :-

( Satisfying upper bounds )

$ ^{13} \mathrm{ C }_{5} \ - $ $ ^{4 + 6 - 1} \mathrm{ C }_{6 - 1} 
 \ {-} \  ^{4 + 6 - 1} \mathrm{ C } _ {6 - 1} + 1 $

We have added one because $ N_a = 9 $ and $ N_b = 11 $ is subtracted one time from each case

In the final answer we also take care of the fact that minimum value of B is 7 whereas maximum of A is 8 ( So we subtract all values of  $A \ge 9 $  , so in the second Combination in the subscripted part we get 4 by 20  - ( 9 + 7 ) and in second case we get 4 by 20 - (11 + 5 )

Comment: If the objects are identical these numbers seem way too high. Think about how you would describe a solution to me. One (potential) solution might be $N_a = 8, N_b=12$. That's a complete description of one of the ways to do this assignment. There just aren't very many of these descriptions. Surely not 1036 of them!

Answer (score 1):

What you are calling the "beggar's method" is more commonly known as [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

However, the problem is not in the nomenclature: you have messed up the numbers. To solve your problem,

To take care of the lower limits, distribute $5$ to $A$ and $7$ to $B$ so now there are only $8$ left to distribute to the two

*But here we are running into a problem with numbers.*
We have $8$ to distribute, but we can only distribute a maximum of $3$ more to each of  $A$ and $B$ due to the upper limits, which means *all the objects can't be distributed, as stipulated*

So unless you give proper figures, the problem can't be solved.

Comment: Read Theorem $2$ of the link I have given to get a proper understanding of stars and bars. I don't know from where you have brought in a figure of $6$, there are only $2$ people, the distribution of all $20$ objects without any lower/upper bounds would be $\binom{20+2-1}{2-1} = 21$